# What is dedjatch?

Tags: meaning, translation

Reading Rimbaud's [letters](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=-c6qA8yyguIC&pg=PA80&dq=%22it%20was%20full%20of%20wrong%20turns%22&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA-a-P-6HfAhWEAhAIHXJUA9cQ6AEIMDAB#v=snippet&q=dedjatch&f=false) and [biography](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=NDR0BgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=a%20season%20in%20hell%20carre&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigpIiRjKLfAhUiqYsKHXcuBkkQ6AEIKTAA#v=snippet&q=dedjatch&f=false), there's a sentence:

"I will feel that the Dedjatch has robbed me to the tune of 866"

I fail to find the meaning of the word in the dictionaries, help me understand it, please? Is it some local term?

Comment: Which letter/biography? Is this in translation or original? What was the sentence/paragraph before? etc etc. Just asking for context (because this is definitely not a common English term.

Comment: @Mitch I've added the links.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Amharic, the primary language in Ethiopia (or Abyssinia at the time of Rimbaud's writing), **Dejazmatch or ጽጅዝምች (sometimes Dejatch)** means literally

> [Keeper of the Gate](https://www.ethiopiancrown.org/traditional.htm)

or more in terms of functioning role, translated as

> Governor General

or even

> Prince

The spelling 'Dedjatch' is presumably a francophone spelling ('dj' is how the French spell the rare in French voiced palatal affricate which is 'j' in English).

[Searching for 'dejatch'](https://www.google.com/search?q=Dejatch) yields many sources saying "Prince (Dedatch) Alemayehu" or just "Prince Alemayehu", and the interpretation that 'Dejatch' is a title of nobility works in all the contexts it is mentioned in those texts.

The usual term for 'prince' in Amharic is ልዑል= liuli, the son of the emperor. But translation and cultural choices can be arbitrary and the English (and French and Italian) somehow settled on 'prince' in this situation.

[The list of titles of nobility in Abyssinia](https://www.ethiopiancrown.org/traditional.htm) gives the real correspondence.

Comment: Nice answer, monsieur!